# Debuggin Jetty webapp initialization

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, jetty

Installed latest Jetty 9 on my Debian server using this guide: http://techtraits.com/jetty9install/

When starting without any webapps run perfectly, but when starting with webapps running:

```
# service jetty start
Starting Jetty: . 
FAILED T juuli  8 17:13:24 EEST 2014
```

So I checked the logs/start.log:

```
StartLog Establishing /opt/jetty/logs/start.log on Tue Jul 08 17:13:16 EEST 2014
```

and logs/2014_07_08.stderrout.log:

```
2014-07-08 17:13:17.584:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.0.v20140526
2014-07-08 17:13:17.657:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
```

I tried modifying resources/log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.File=lll.out
```

There is no lll.out nowhere on my server.

I tried running it as:

```
java -jar start.jar --daemon -DDEBUG=true -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

All I get is:

```
WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --exec
System Property [DEBUG] has been deprecated! (Use org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG instead)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.638:INFO::main: Logging initialized @742ms
2014-07-08 17:21:27.701:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: parse: file:/opt/jetty/etc/jetty.xml
2014-07-08 17:21:27.706:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: parsing: sid=file:/opt/jetty/etc/jetty.xml,pid=null
2014-07-08 17:21:27.720:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: resolveEntity(-//Jetty//Configure//EN, http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.721:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: Redirected entity http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd --> jar:file:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-9.2.0.v20140526.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/xml/configure_9_0.dtd
2014-07-08 17:21:27.828:DBUG:oejuc.ContainerLifeCycle:main: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3d82c5f3 added {qtp458209687{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0},AUTO}
2014-07-08 17:21:27.834:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML get ThreadPool
2014-07-08 17:21:27.846:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML qtp458209687{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0}.setMinThreads(10)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.847:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML qtp458209687{STOPPED,10<=0<=200,i=0,q=0}.setMaxThreads(200)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.847:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML qtp458209687{STOPPED,10<=0<=200,i=0,q=0}.setIdleTimeout(60000)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.850:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML qtp458209687{STOPPED,10<=0<=200,i=0,q=0}.setDetailedDump(false)
2014-07-08 17:21:27.853:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML new class org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler
2014-07-08 17:21:27.853:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: using normal mapping
2014-07-08 17:21:27.856:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML call addBean
... A lot of quiet debu log ...
2014-07-08 17:21:35.508:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/IterableBridge.class
2014-07-08 17:21:35.508:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/ShortBridge.class
2014-07-08 17:21:35.510:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/CalendarBridge.class
2014-07-08 17:21:35.512:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/NumberBridge.class
2014-07-08 17:21:35.513:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/UriBridge.class
2014-07-08 17:21:35.514:DBUG:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp458209687-12: Scanning class from jar jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/las/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/LongNumericFieldBridge.class
Killed
```

The same setup with different webapp has worked for me in other cases. It would be fine if I could conjure out some type of error message, but I have been struggling, without luck, to get it for some time now. If someone has a suggestion I would really appreciate it.